# How to write a program that ask the user a lower-case letter and then print tower of letters beginning from letter "a" up to the letter entered?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a sample. **Note:** Lists and built in string functions cannot be used. From the sample runs, you can see that the tower of letters follows this pattern: it starts from 3 rows of letter "a", then 5 rows of letter "b", then 7 rows of letter "c", and so forth, up to the user-entered letter. Will really appreciate your answer.

To which letter you want to print to? d

```
a 
aa
aaa
b 
bb
bbb 
bbbb 
bbbbb
c 
cc
ccc
cccc 
ccccc 
cccccc 
ccccccc
d 
dd
ddd
dddd
ddddd 
dddddd 
ddddddd 
dddddddd 
ddddddddd
```

Here is my attempt to it:

```
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 3):
          print(j * s[i])
```

Comment: Solve your own homework. This is not a python skill related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be much easier with an enumeration.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def letter_pyramid():
    data = raw_input('Enter stop: ')
    data = ascii_lowercase.partition(data)[0] + data

    for i, j in enumerate(data):
        for k in range(0, 2 * i + 4):
            print j * k

letter_pyramid()
```

Comment: But it has to be without any in built string functions.

Comment: The OP has used range and len. I think he's referring to modules like itertools and whatnot.

Comment: Can you modify my code and add a break statement so it stops at an entered letter. Will appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the data variable or can you make it a bit more simpler because its a kind of hard for me to understand. Will be thankful.

Comment: If i had to convert it to a function what can i do as i want it to be a function. sorry for my understanding. thanks anyways

Comment: Basically, we ask the user to input a letter. Then we split the alphabet at the specified letter, grab the letters before it, and add the removed letter back in.

Comment: I added it in a function too.